# Sum of integers and zêta functions

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

I am working on generalizing some works from the usual rational case to general number fields. That implies some technical changes I am not really at ease with. For instance:

$$\sum_{m \leqslant X} m = \frac{X(X-1)}{2} = \frac{X^2}{2} + O(X)$$

Generalizing it, I end with the following sum to estimate, where $\mathfrak{m}$ stands for ideals of the integer ring $\mathcal{O}_F$ (analogues of the integers in the case of $\mathbf{Q}$) and $N$ is the norm on $F$, and I would like to prove this kind of estimate:

$$\sum_{N\mathfrak{m} \leqslant X} N\mathfrak{m} = \zeta_F(-1) \frac{X^2}{2} + O(X)$$

where $\zeta_F(-1)$ stands for the value of the zêta function of $F$ at -1. Is it true, and how can I prove this kind of results (more than formally saying something like $\zeta(-1) = \sum N\mathfrak{m}$ ?

Thanks in advance for any clue or idea ;)

Comment: you want to prove that the value $\zeta_F(-1)$ of the [Dedekind_zeta_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function)   (not the residue, which is $0$) can be interpreted as the ratio between $\sum_{N(m) \le X, m \in O_F} N(m)$ and $\sum_{m \le X, m \in \mathbb{N}} m$.

Comment: @user1952009 In wich case I should also be able to evaluate $\sum N(m)$, that is to say reducing it to the sum of integers $k$, and weighting by the number of ideals $m$ of given norm $k$ : do we know well these numbers ?

Comment: Yes indeed, it should be the $N(m)$ !

Comment: and no, for the estimate we don't care of the value of $\zeta_F(s)$ at $s=-1$, but only of the residue at the pole at $s=1$, i.e. the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula

Comment: so the residue of $\zeta_F(s)$ at $s=1$ tells us that $$\sum_{ N(m) \le x, m \in O_F} 1 \sim C x$$  with $C = Res(\zeta_F(s),1)$ do you know how to prove this ? and then (because $s=1$ is the only pole of $\zeta_F(s)$) even that $$\sum_{ N(m) \le x, m \in O_F} 1 = C x + \mathcal{O}(1)$$. finally prove that $$\sum_{ N(m) \le x} N(m) =  \mathcal{O}(x) + C \sum_{n \le x} n = C\frac{x^2}{2}+ \mathcal{O}(x)$$

Comment: Perfect, this link with the residue at $s=1$ is exactly the missing piece, thank you very much @user1952009 !

Comment: thank you too, I have a good experience with Dirichlet series and $\zeta(s)$, but not so much with $\zeta_F(s)$

Comment: @reuns The result should not be with a remainder $O(x)$, but $O(x^{2-\delta_F})$ where $\delta_F = 2(1+[F:\mathbf{Q}])^{-1}$.